# How to get a random item from a list, tuple, or string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python and came across a function :

```
choice(seq)
```

Here "seq" can be a string, tuple or a list.
But, when I'm using it in terminal it throws an error :

```
NameError: name 'choice' is not defined
```

The way I used this function was :
(On Terminal)

```
choice("hello")
```

but as stated above it throwed an error.

I may be using it the wrong way, so if there's any corrections to my method or any other alternative way by which I can get a random item from a list, string and a tuple , I would welcome all the suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't imported it yet, i.e: `from random import choice`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import function choice from random module in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from random import choice
print "choice([1, 2, 3, 5, 9]) : ", choice([1, 2, 3, 5, 9])
print "choice('A String') : ", choice('A String')
```

Output

```
choice([1, 2, 3, 5, 9]) :  2
choice('A String') :  n
```

Comment: `choice` isn't a module.

Comment: oops sorry , random module , choice would be a function